# Android Studio Update JavaAppletPlugin M1 Error

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio

I'm a Flutter developer. I use M1 Pro chip. I want to Update my android studio but i have this error message.

java.io.IOException: An absolute link: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin -> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin

```
05/03 14:00:18 INFO  PatchFileCreator.prepareAndValidate - Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1 -> Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2
05/03 14:00:18 INFO  Patch.forEach - Validating installation... [4239 actions]
05/03 14:00:18 ERROR Runner.install - prepare failed
java.io.IOException: An absolute link: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin -> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
    at com.intellij.updater.Digester.digestRegularFile(Digester.java:50)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.digestFile(Patch.java:450)
    at com.intellij.updater.DeleteAction.validate(DeleteAction.java:42)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.lambda$validate$0(Patch.java:292)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:438)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.validate(Patch.java:291)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.prepareAndValidate(PatchFileCreator.java:109)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.install(Runner.java:413)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner._main(Runner.java:221)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.main(Runner.java:49)
```

java version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing)

I need Android Studio Update. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Facing the same issue, I'm postponing the update for now, did you find a solution? I think I used the same scripts as the one you described below

Comment: As a workaround, I uninstalled Android Studio from Applications folder and installed the new version. The issue still awaits a permanent solution. @gginter

Answer (score 0):

I have used these commands for flutter before. Could the problem be with these codes?

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
ln -s ../jre jdk
ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
```